# execute methods of all derived classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a command line application. It has one abstract class and every command is a class derived from that class. Every class has virtual function help. I have a command help. That command should execute help method of every command. How can I achieve that. In case, I didn't explain clearly...

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void help() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {   
public:
    virtual void help();
};


class Derived1 : public Base {  
public:
    virtual void help();
};


class Derived2 : public Base {  
public:
    virtual void help();
};

class DerivedToCallEveryHelp : public Base {    
//How can I execute help functions of every dervied class
};
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: How do you keep track of the commands in your app?

Comment: `help` needs an instance for each subclass. where are they?

Comment: The requirement doesn't make sense because you don't have any instances of the classes. You can't just execute non-`static` methods without an instance.

Comment: @StoryTeller I have another class Engine, I register commands into a map of string and a pointer to a derived class.

Comment: -1: i dont see, why you should do such garbage. derive a class to implement a special function behavior is clear, but one of the derived classes cannot be able (except members of each child class) to call each individual 'specialized' function.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore This is not my actual app. This is just the class hierarchy. OK, I want to have a method of DerivedToCallEveryHelp that will do the job. I mean i want to create an instance of that class and call a method which will execute help methods

Comment: @Zaiborg, what!? Using command objects is a common idiom. Your'e not very clear in your critique and I feel your downvote is unjustified.

Comment: @khajvah, no need to reinvent the wheel. Just have the `activate` implementation of the help command iterate over the map and call `help' for each instance.

Comment: @StoryTeller: lets play this through ... one abstract class, where every class gets derived (lets say 20 classes) and you have implemented the `derivedToCallEveryHelp` as mentioned ... if you add another class, you have to change `DerivedToCallEveryHelp` and so i dont see the meaning of using it

Comment: @Zaiborg, I'm afraid, my friend, that you didn't get the gist of what the OP is doing.

Comment: @Zaiborg My question is that. I want to have that DerivedToCallEverHelp, that will automatically call every help of every class. But I just didn't explain clearly I think, anyway, I did that by iterating over the map

Comment: @khajvah: it is your code; but i am against something like this, cause whenever you add a class and you forget to add that to the map, you may have problems finding the reason for it. especially when your library gets bigger.

Comment: @Zaiborg Well, in main(), I register all commands (add class to map), so if I do not add a class to map (do not register a command), I do not need to execute the help method of that class

Comment: @khajvah it will be the same without polymorphism, just have a function that allocates the objects from any class that is needed and call the wanted functions ...

Comment: Yes, maybe you know better, because it's less than a month that I am doing OOP programming. I will write another version like you said and compare. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the collection that either has an instance of all your classes, or a factory function to create one. Then just call .Help() on each.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer. I will iterate over the map of commands like @StoryTeller said in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a collection of point to Base type and execute them one buy one.
BTW, **DerivedToCallEveryHelp** should be an independent class, it doesn't need to inherit from **Base**

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class DerivedToCallEveryHelp
public:  
  DerivedToCallEveryHelp()
  {
      helps.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived()));
      helps.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived1()));
      helps.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived2()));
  }

  void Execute()
  {
     for(auto & item: helps)
     {
          item->help();
     }
  }

private:
  std::vector<std::unqiue_ptr<Base> helps;

};
```